# What does mean expression "variableName;" in Solidity?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I can not find any information about this expression in docs. There is the following code on [Ehternaut Re-entrancy task](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xe6BA07257a9321e755184FB2F995e0600E78c16D) .

```
function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
  if(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount) {
    (bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
    if(result) {
      _amount;
    }
    balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
  }
}
```

What does `_amount;` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(result) {
  _amount;
}
```

This snippet effectively does nothing. You can safely ignore it, as it's not related to the reentrancy vulnerability.

Without the mentioned snippet, the compiler would raise a warning about unused `result` variable. If they didn't declare the `result` variable, there would be another warning about not checking the result of the low-level call. And if they just left the condition block empty - yes, another warning about empty block.

So my best guess is that the authors just wanted to clear the warnings, and chose this way to do that.